# Regex for password complexity regarding safe ascii characters for URLEncode

Tags: regex, passwords, special-characters, url-encoding

i'm working on a password check for the following requirements:

A minimum of 8 characters, which must contain:

- at least one upper case character
- at least one lower case character
- at least one special character of: `*_!.()-`

It should not matter if the characters are consecutive or not.

So far, my regex seems to basically work:

> `^(?=(.*[0-9]){1,})(?=(.*[\*\_\!\.\(\)\-]){1,})(?=(.*[a-z]){1,})(?=(.*[A-Z]){1,}).{8,}$`

But i'm having trouble to "allow only" the specified special character set. E.g.
"Sample!1234" is matched, but "Sa%mple!123" is matched as well - which has to fail under all cirumstances because of the not allowed special char "%", indifferent if there is any other allowed special character. I think the issue is with the dot quantifier, that considers any character, and I have not been able to solve this yet...

For better understanding of the technical background: We operate a windows application (Dynamics NAV) that uses an custom developed interface that has to authenticate on an IBM Websphere by HTTP request / SOAP envelope. The web service itself is able to validate the user/password against active directory. I have encountered an issue within the interface app, when it comes to special characters, that are used for windows password complexity. On transmission, where a special character like %, § or + is used and user and pass are URLEncoded by the interface app, the authentication between the webservice and active directory will force the account to be locked, due to a password mismatch. From my perspective the IBM Webservice is not URLDecoding the password string properly, which is no issue as long it not required to URLEncode a character...

Comment: You allow all characters but a newline here: `.{8,}`. With lookaheads, you only *require* something to be *present*. **What characters are allowed?** If you allow anything but `%`, replace `.{8,}` with `[^%]{8,}`.

Comment: The only allowed special characters are listed above:
• at least one special character of: "*_!.()-"
or in other words: all other chars must be disallowed. But since i do not have control, which keyboard layout the end user will have, the eclusion by inverting like [^%$§"'#+~|<>,;:?ß\{/}][µ^°²³] is just the beginning -.-

Comment: If those characters required are the only characters allowed, why not use `^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[*_!.()-])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z*_!.()-]{8,}$`?

Comment: That seems to work. Thanks.
Wasn't aware on the second explicit block [0-9a-zA-Z*_!.()-]{8,}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those characters required are the only characters allowed, just replace last `.` to `[0-9a-zA-Z*_!.()-]`:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[*_!.()-])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z*_!.()-]{8,}$
```

Also, I suggest removing unnecessary limiting quantifiers and groups from the lookaheads as they do not make any difference.